# Ubuntu juju and Eucalyptus?

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, eucalyptus, juju

Has anyone used juju (ensemble) to deploy softwares on Eucalyptus' instances successfully ?

Although the official FAQ says that [juju is only support EC2 ( currently )](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/faq.html),
but I've found someone ([ex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65364/how-can-i-configure-multiple-deployment-environments-for-juju).) got OpenStack setting in juju's `environment.yaml`

But when I tried the similar settings in my file, juju will throw `HTTP 500 ERROR` or **still
connect to AWS** and complained that the access keys is not in records.

Or there are some other ways to mass deploy softwares on cloud instances ?

My juju server is also an Ubuntu 11.10 instance; booted from simple EMI from [Ubuntu Cloud Images](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/) . And it can access to the cloud controller server.

Answer (score 1):

Due to https://bugs.launchpad.net/txaws/+bug/907450 Juju currently does not support Eucalyptus.

Soon this bug will be fixed and you will be able to use Juju on Eucalyptus.